# Android Studio does not recognize my phone as an android, but adb sees it

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, adb

I've recently reinstalled my SDK. When trying to run the app, the device, although connected through USB, it is not displayed in the devices menu. When clicking troubleshoot device connections, when scanning for devices, it detects the phone, but not as an android. 
(macos)

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK > platform-tool and Open terminal here.
Then fire below command

1. adb kill-server
2. abd start-server

Finally don't forget to enabled the **USB debugging** from **developer** options.

Comment: Already done that. It still does not appear on the list of connected devices. Also tried adb devices and it is displayed there.

Comment: Which OS is there

Comment: And is your mobile show debugging option in notification panel of android

Comment: Yes, I've tried switching between MTP and PTP. No progress. I'm also using Android File Transfer on Mac and it opens it as soon as I plug the mobile in. It works just fine.